# Asynchronous Sockets with .NET seem to have an issue with the thread pool

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, asyncsocket

I have noticed the example for Asynchronous sockets sending and receiving form MSDN, linked below, does not work. What is happening is that the thread created in Receive with the BeginReceive doesn't start until the thread running on the method StartClient exits that method. The receiveDone.WaitOne() event is thus never called as the signaler in the Receive methods never gets hit as the worker thread created by the beginReceive will not start until the method StartClient returns.

I also see quite a few references to this issue posted around the net.

Does anyone have some ideas on this issue?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I don't understand the question, I thought this was in Asynchronous Sockets...why is it tagged `ThreadPool`?

Comment: It will start to run long, *long* after the method that called BeginReceive() completed.  Network connections are much slower than the processor.  Even longer if you use a debugger.  Which is rather the point of async sockets, you never want to wait for it.  If the callback never runs then you're doing it wrong.  Probably by trying to connect to a machine that doesn't respond or is blocked by a firewall.

Comment: @Aron: I tagged the question with ThreadPool as I couldn't account for the behavior, it's like the threadPool ran out of threads and will not allow the beginReceive to start until a thread was available. This is most likely not the case though, as there are only about 8 threads used when this call is made.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks for your comment, however this is for an server that I wrote 14 years ago and is running in production with no issues. The only issue is that while updating the client app, I decided to use the .NET async methods and have encountered this issue. The specific issue is that in this example from MS the beginRead will not call the AsyncCallback until the method startClient returns, regardless of how long I wait, if I am in the debugger or otherwise. It's like the AsyncCallback thread was joined to the thread running the startClient method.

Comment: @KarlEasterly Is that happening with the exact same code from MSDN, both in separate console applications? Also, note that the sample is missing a check for the operation completing synchronously - if the `IAsyncResult` returned from the `BeginXXX` has `CompletedSynchronously` set, the callback will not be called - you have to call it yourself. This is quite unlikely to happen on network, but if you're testing on localhost, it could occur, especially with all the waits involved.

Comment: @Luaan: The CompletedSynchronously property is false, however the IsComplete has been set to true. I am trying to understand if the IsComplete is related to the Async call itself, or if it is indicating that the underlying socket receive has completed, and there is not more data to receive or the socket has closed or other. I tend to think it would indicate that only the Async call itself completed.

Comment: I have tentatively had luck implementing a receive timeout and calling Socket.Shutdown to trigger the Async callback to be invoked. I am starting to think this issue is related to understanding when the beginRead callback is actually triggered. I cannot seem to find out the details relating to when the callback is actually called. Socket Shutdown, 1+ bytes and a timeout between received bytes, or the remote socket shutdowns, or a timeout in general. I think if I knew the rules when the callback is triggered, I would see the issue.

Comment: I forgot to mention, Yes, it's the exact code from MSDN for the client only, minus the host name and port items. I am connecting to a server written many moons ago and the server is functioning just fine. The server, when it receives a command packet simply sends a ACK and closes it's socket.

Comment: Well, the server should send a response (either synchronously or in the write callback handler) and shutdown, then close. If you just kill the connection, the client has no way of knowing the connection has died. And since the MSDN's client doesn't do any heartbeats, it really will never know. Note that by default, TCP messages smaller than the buffer size will tend to be buffered for about 200ms before being actually sent.

Answer (score 2):

To have a full sample, you need to build both the server and the client, and run them both. The `Send` in the server sample is there to send a *response* to the client's request.

`BeginSend` (and the other `BeginXXX` methods) starts an asynchronous I/O request immediately - it doesn't need any threads. The callback will be run as soon as the I/O request is fulfilled (which is partially handled by the physical hardware of the NIC, and partially by the kernel), on a I/O thread on the thread pool. As such, the sample client is written using asynchronous I/O, but otherwise is pretty much synchronous. The `sendDone.WaitOne();` is completely unnecessary in this case, but it doesn't hurt either.

.NET's asynchronous sockets use IOCP, not multi-threading. The basic idea is that you've got a couple of I/O threads, which are used to process the asynchronous I/O "pushes" from the OS. The asynchronous I/O itself doesn't need any threads, from the thread pool or otherwise, you only need a thread for the callback (in this case, the `AcceptCallback`, `ReadCallback` and similar methods).

In any case, this is an outdated sample, and as with all samples, you shouldn't use it out of the box. It's pretty much the simplest asynchronous socket server you can build. In truth, this is one of the better samples - it correctly handles socket shutdown, reads the data properly, and it even handles primitive message framing (the `<EOF>`).

To explain the sample a bit more in detail, there's a few things that are going on at the same time.

The main thread in the server is only doing one thing - repeatedly starting asynchronous I/O "requests" to accept incoming TCP connections. The wait handle is there to avoid unnecessary polling/looping - you can see that it's reset before doing `BeginAccept` (asynchronous I/O request to accept connection), and set in the callback (`AcceptCallback`) - this will allow the main thread to cycle again and accept a *new* connection.

The `AcceptCallback` also starts an asynchronous I/O request, this time to receive data. When the network interface receives data for the given socket, the data is saved into a DMA buffer, and a callback is posted to a thread pool I/O thread. This is where the `ReadCallback` method executes.

So, as you can see, if there's no requests, there's no threads except for the main thread (which doesn't really matter, since exiting the main thread would terminate the application). Only when a callback comes, a thread is taken from the I/O pool, and as soon as the callback completes (almost immediately), is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I understand your comments about the IOCP but I didn't know this. I also understand that I shouldn't use this out of the box, I am just doing the initial prototype of the sample provided to get proof of concept. 

The key issue I am having is that the beginReceive is an asynchronous method call. It should call the callback method independent of the state of the thread that called beginReceive. What is happening, is that the asyncCallback's behavior is as though it's a thread joined to the thread that is running in the startClient method. I am puzzled...